# Simulate OUTER JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have a somewhat exotic question. In order for some old software to be run against a newer version of MS SQL Server, I have to get rid of outer join operators "`*=`" and "`=*`". Unfortunately I can only manipulate the where clause of an otherwise dynamically built sql query. There is no way to redesign the query as a whole. Hence my question:

Is there a way to simulate an outer join via the where clause without using outer join operators?

The goal is to get the database from compatibility level 80 (i. e. "2000") which supports the operators to the newest level which does not support the operators.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would need to show an example.  I'm pretty sure the answer is no in general, but perhaps in some specific cases.

Comment: I was afraid the answer may be no :-/ The mechanism in the background is a custom O/R-mapper, that uses Attributes on Properties of C# classes to generate joins employing outer join operators. As a result there is no specific case.

Comment: Does the software insert the `WHERE` keyword automatically or can you control that? If it does then you might be able to insert the `OUTER JOIN` syntax first, if not then I think you're out of luck sorry.

Comment: Left join is a UNION ALL of the corresponding inner join with unmatched inner join rows extended by nulls. So you can't use WHERE to extract a left from an inner. However you can cross join the original 2 tables with a row of nulls or add a null row to the right table then select appropriately in a WHERE. But it's not clear what transformations are permitted or why. It would help if you would describe clearly & fully what ranges of transformations you can & cannot do to what ranges of \* queries. What is stopping you from transforming an entire query--SQL or ORM--to use keyword joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to all contributers I was able to think about the problem a little more thoroughly. That led me to the conclusion that the problem has no solution.

Since a cross join is lacking some of the rows an outer join could have, you can't come from the first to the second by filtering out rows with a where condition.

Thanks everyone for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Real `OUTER JOIN` behaviour may be impossible. But, depending on your real life requirements, maybe you can using something like this:

```
Declare @test1 table(ID int) 
Declare @test2 table(ID int) 

Insert @test1
Values(1)
,     (2)

Insert @test2
Values(1)
,     (3)

Select *
From  @test1 t1
,     @test2 t2
Where exists(select null 
             from  @test2 t3 
             where t3.ID = t1.ID  
                or t2.ID is null)
```

[rextester demo](https://rextester.com/ZEYVE31876)

Like I said, it isn't a real `OUTER JOIN`, but maybe if you play with it a bit more you'll get what you need.

Best of luck.